# Upper bounding the minimum distance between points (in high dimensional space)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

Given $m>n$ points $p_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$, how to *upper*-bound $\min_{i,j}|p_i-p_j|$ across all possible sets of points, where $|\cdot|$ denotes Euclidean distance?

I think we can make two simplifying assumptions (reducing to point distributions that maximize the distance between points). First, all points have the same distance from the origin, i.e. $\rho=|p_i|=\max_j|p_j|$ for all $i\in[m]$. Furthermore, the points are equally spaced out on the $n$-sphere of radius $\rho$.

For the case of small $n$ and large $m$, research has been done from the perspective of [spherical codes](http://neilsloane.com/packings/). I'm instead interested in high dimensional cases with large $n$ and any special $m>n$.

Given the two simplifications, for the case of $m=2n$, we may assume two points $p_{k_1},p_{k_2}$ lie on the axis of each dimension $k$, pointing in opposite directions, i.e. $p_{k_1}=\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k},p_{k_2}=-\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k}$ for $k\in[n]$. That is, $p_{2k}=\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k}$ and $p_{2k-1}=-\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k}$ for $k\in[n]$. In this case, $\min_{i,j}|p_i-p_j| = |\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k}-\rho\cdot\textbf{e}_{k'}| = \sqrt{\rho^2+(-\rho)^2} = \rho\sqrt{2}$, for any distinct $k,k'\in[n]$. If the general case has no simple formula, how about extending to $m=tn$ for some integers $t>2$?

Comment: I believe this is a hard problem in the general case, though it may be tractable in some special cases. There are several pointers in related questions on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060934/create-n-points-that-are-spaced-as-far-as-possible-within-a-d-dimensional-sphere) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123194/how-to-distribute-points-evenly-on-the-surface-of-hyperspheres-in-higher-dimensi).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the pointers! Yes, any special cases still of interest.